# Java For Loop Confusion (iteration) "Don't know why it still went through!"

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration, conditional-statements

So I was trying to figure out if the the first iteration in a for loop does not go through the termination condition.

Since when I called it in the main method with an input of 4 `IsPrime(4)` the for loop still went through. I was expecting it to not go through since `i = 2`  and `n/2 = 4/2 = 2` which will be `2 == 2` which will meet the condition to terminate but it went through and I got the right output but I don't get why it did not fail.

Please help.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n){

    if(n <= 1){
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++){
        if(n % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `<=` simply means *less than or equal*. 2 is equal to 2.

Comment: but shouldn't that stop the iteration?

Comment: `for (int i = 2; i < n/2; i++) { ... }` says start i at 2 and loop while i is less than or equal to n/2. This means the condition evaluates to false (hence terminating the loop) when i is *greater* than n/2. This happens first when i is 3.

Comment: Wow i just derped real hard there thank you. I get it now

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop condition says *continue while* `i <= n/2`.

If you start with `n == 4` then `n/2 == 2`. On the first iteration `i == 2` so the for loop condition `2 <= 2` is true and it will iterate once.

Then `i++` is executed so now `i == 3` and fails the condition so there is no second iteration.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a confusion around how for loop works. Let's see the operation on a per-iteration basis :

Iteration 1 :

- `i = 2`
- `i <= 2` ? --> True
- `n % i == 0` ? --> `2 % 2 == 0`? True
- `return false`
- End of function

Now let's assume your for loop looked something like this :

```
 for(int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++){
        if(n % i == 0){
            System.out.println("Remainder is 0");
        }
    }
```

Then the following will the iteration sequence :

Iteration 1

- `i = 2`
- `i <= 2` ? --> True
- `n % i == 0` ? --> 2 % 2 == 0? True
- print --> Remainder is 0
- `i++` --> i = 3 now

Iteration 2

- `i = 3`
- `i <= 3` ? --> False
- Cannot proceed further. For loop condition failed.
- End of function

Comment: Yea I was thinking of the opposite. I was thinking that when the condition was met it will stop the loop. I just realized it was the other way around thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: glad it helped. It is confusing sometimes :)